# How can i find shrines nearby location

Tags: qgis

How can i find shrines/complex/institute nearby location in qgis and highlight them. The below image is similar to my shape files which contains all information of all attributes,i don't know python, i was using spatial query to find location within area or beside roads, now i want to find complex, malls near to my location and highlight them.
[image: Location image]

Comment: This image looks like a screenshot from Google Maps. Your data is more important. What data do you have, and in which format? And where will the input come from?

Comment: i have all attribute as shown in image like all complex/malls/institute in that area, i want to find mall/shrine near to my complex  and highlight.

Comment: CY5, judging from the series of questions you're asking you are clearly determined to achieve a goal. That is admirable! We would be better able to help you if used some of that determination to add more detail to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector->Geo processing tools -> Buffer ( add tour source layer or select feature from source layer) -> results file, load results file -> Vector -> Geo processing tools -> intersect/clip ( results layer and what you want layer ) -> results layer -> Load results 2 layer and now you have all data from what you want layer which intersect with buffer